# Separating this code into a header and cpp file

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am new to modern c++, so I have difficulties to separate header and cpp file with below code (AES encryption and decryption). For example, how would I separate the code?

https://gist.github.com/edwardstock/3c992fb71320391d3639696328a61115

Comment: Why would you want to? The reason for separating the code would determine how you do it. Myself, I can't see any reason why you would want to separate that particular code.

Comment: Because I want to convert it to common function, and use in other function to encrypt & decrypt with AES. The code is not my gist, I want to reuse it.

Comment: Then the answer below seems reasonable. The API is the encrypt and decrypt functions. The crucial thing is to understand the difference between a declaration and a definition. You will have to add function declarations for encrypt and decrypt to your header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) goes to the header file. That includes:

- Any classes your users might want to use
- Any function/variable [*declarations*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1410563/10147399) your user might want to use

The implementation of this API goes to the CPP file:

- Most function definitions
- Most variable definitions
- Implementation details (classes, functions your user will never need, etc.)

There are exceptions, like inline function *definitions* might still go to the header, and templates might have to be in header files as entirely, but this is the general overview.